# Pop from index 0 without moving all elements

Tags: python, list

I am using Python 3. I want to optimize a function used for removing the first element in a list with `pop()`. Instead of moving all the data one index lower, how can I make it just increment the index by 1 for every element?
So that the internal storage is still available but just unused. 
When it removes the first element, the second element becomes the new index to be the first element, the third one to be the second etc.
So that I don't have to move all the elements in a list after a pop but just move their index to keep the internal storage as it is.

Comment: Python lists do all of this for you, they don't move anything around and do exactly what you describe. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Are you entirely sure that `del mylist[0]` is so very wasteful?

Comment: If I use the in Python integrated pop(), does it really just keep the internal capacity storage and rearrange the index for each element?
I want to have some kind of ring storage, with no real beginning or ending (size-1), but rather just a beginning index and an end index

Comment: Yes, but Google could have told you that, too. Regarding the ring buffer: Again, why reinvent the wheel when there is [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)?

Comment: If I Google the pop function, I can only find that it removes the first element by index and returns its value - but it says nowhere that it keeps the internal storage for later usage like adding an item via append()

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
lst.pop(0)
```

The python lists have exactly the behaviour you describe.

Comment: Thank you :)
I didn't know that pop() does exactly that :D

Comment: It's polite to cite commenters when they've pointed this out 6 minutes before you posted this answer, which has the same information. You could improve this post by providing a link to documentation showing that Python lists do this.

Comment: sorry, I did not want to offend anyone. I had started my answer when the question had no comments yet, but left it unattended before hitting the post button.